# Using AJAX with Drag/Drop jQuery plugin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop

Based off of [this Drag/Drop example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130437/how-can-i-drop-an-image-to-a-container-and-then-update-the-container-based-on-wha/5130533#5130533)

If I want to increment the the value (vote) in one of my database tables after the Draggable is Dropped to its container, would I just use $.ajax() within this block below?

> ```
>     drop: function( event, ui ) {
>         $( this )
>             .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
>             .find( "p" )
>                 .html( "Dropped!" );
>     }
> ```

or would that method not work with this particular plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that would work.

```
drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
        .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
    $.ajax(/*** your code ***/);
}
```